# Extract a string from a returned API call in XML

Tags: bash, awk, grep, stdout, cut

I would like to take XML API output and extract the name (name="vPC-NAME") from a file. Since this call returns multiple names I need to be able to search for any text between the double quotes.

I have tried

```
awk 'name="*"' PCMappings_Result2.xml

cat file | egrep -o 'name=\"*\"




<pcAggrIf activePorts="1" adminSt="up" autoNeg="on" bw="0" childAction="" createTime="18074:07:16:08.069" ctrl="fast-sel-hot-stdby,graceful-conv,susp-individual" delay="1" descr="" dn="node-101/sys/aggr-[po4]" dot1qEtherType="0x8100" ethpmCfgFailedBmp="" ethpmCfgFailedTs="00:00:00:00.000" ethpmCfgState="0" fcotChannelNumber="Channel32" fop="eth1/45" hashDist="adaptive" id="po4" inhBw="unspecified" iod="67" isPlatformSupported="yes" isReflectiveRelayCfgSupported="Supported" lastBundleMbr="eth1/47" lastBundleTime="18074:07:16:08.318" lastSt="successful" lastStCause="" lastTime="18074:07:16:08.318" lastUnbundleMbr="unspecified" lastUnbundleTime="00:00:00:00.000" layer="Layer2" lcOwn="local" lif="0" linkDebounce="100" linkLog="default" loadDeferStartTime="00:00:00:00.000" ltl="8198" maxActive="16" maxLinks="16" mdix="auto" medium="broadcast" minLinks="1" modTs="2019-06-27T07:51:04.547+00:00" mode="trunk" monPolDn="uni/infra/moninfra-default" mtu="9000" name="vPC-NAME"/>
```

Comment: Using regex to manipulate XML is a bad idea. This is a common FAQ. Look for `xmlstarlet`, `xmllint`, `xsltproc` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should proper tool for XML, but if no option are available, this will work:

```
awk -F'name="' 'NF>1{split($2,a,"\"");print a[1]}' file
vPC-NAME
```

- Divide the line by `name="` as Field Separator
- And if line has at least two fields `NF>1` do:
- Split last part `$2` by `"` and store it in array `a`
- Print first part of array `a[1]`

If there are multiple name in one line, we need to loop trough the line:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^name/) {split($i,a,"\"");print a[2]}}' file
n3k-p45
esxi2-vpc
```

Comment: Thank you for the response you are correct. This is what I was looking for. Unfortunately the programs available on the system are quite limited and their is no external internet access to add additional programs. One thing that is interesting. When there is more than one instance of name= the command completes, but errors out to the following message. ```awk: can't open file *awk
 input record number 8, file *awk
 source line number 1```

Comment: @if you post an example line, I am sure that I can fix that.

Comment: Here is the return output from two different API GETs.

Comment: Here is example API output, I shortend it
```
 <pcAggrIf activePorts="1" autoNeg="o" delay="1" descr="" dn="node-101/sys/aggr-[po4]" lastSt="successful" linkDebounce="100" linkLog="default" loadDeferStartTime="00:00:00:00.000" ltl="8198" maxActive="16" mode="trunk" mtu="900" name="n3k-p45" operChannelMode="active"/>

 <pcAggrIf adminSt="up" autoNeg="o"  delay="1" descr="" dn="node-101/sys/aggr-[po1]" lastSt="successful" linkDebounce="100" linkLog="default" loadDeferStartTime="00:00:00:00.000" ltl="8196" maxActive="16" mode="trunk" mtu="900" name="esxi2-vpc" operChannelMode="active"/>
```

Comment: @fly2809 the name are on the same line? Do you like both output?  See updated post.

Comment: That is it Thank You!